# How to make Nb-Card Scrollable

Tags: angular, nebular, ngx-admin

I am using Nb-Card and I want to make that card scrollable. I am using NB-card in NbDialog box and as the browser size is reduced the content of Nb-card is not seen also when I reduce the card size the content of the card is getting ommited. So how to add a scroll bar in Nb-card?

By the below anwer I am achieving vertical scroll, but if the content is large I also need a horizontal scroll which is not working. So how to also add horizontal scroll?

Comment: Have you tried to add an inline style property to Nb-Card?
`style="overflow-y: scroll"`

Comment: @Ivndsky yeah I tried, not working. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to your Css file:-

```
.classname{
  max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Add to your html file:-

```
<nb-card class="classname">
</nb-card>
```